# twitter stream api using Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, api, twitter, stream

I am trying to find a way to use the twitter stream API in a Flex application, just like TweetDeck(air) does, does anyone know how I can implement this? I tried to search for libraries but unsuccessful :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you researched the Twitter API?

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation

You can use that information to write your own integration code between twitter and ActionScript / Flex.

There are some libraries out there if you google on [Twitter ActionScript Libraries](http://www.google.com/search?q=Twitter+Actionscript+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a):

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#flash

[Tweetr](http://code.google.com/p/tweetr/) from that list is the one I've heard of before.

Also here is a [Robotlegs tutorial](http://insideria.com/2010/06/an-introduction-to-robotlegs-a-2.html) that accesses twitter.

Comment: Thanks Flextras, I am now writing my own implementation :D was hoping to find an already made lib but now ill make it on my own, more fun!